# ¿Por qué me sale éste error en ubuntu 16.10 al instalar apache2?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, ubuntu

Buenas noches.

Acabo de actualizar la versión de ubuntu de 16.04 a la 16.10 y desinstale LAMP por completo(tenía invonvenientes), pero al querer instalar de nueva cuenta LAMP(en especifico apache2 y php 7.0) me sale el siguiente error:

```
 No se pudieron instalar algunos paquetes. Esto puede significar que usted
 pidió una situacion imposible o, si está usando la distribución inestable,
 que algunos paquetes necesarios aún no se han creado o se han sacado de 
 <<Incoming>>. La siguiente información puede ayudar a resolver la situación:

 Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:

 apache2: Depende: apache2-bin (= 2.4.18-ubuntu4) pero no va a instalarse
 E: No se pudieron corregir los problemas, usted ha retenido paquetes rotos.
```

Ya utilicé el comando de `sudo apt-get install -f` y con `sudo dpkg --configure -a` y no me funciona.

Espero me puedan ayudar, de antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Probaste haciendo un `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: Así es, ya usé

apt-get update && apt-get upgrade, apt-get dist-upgrade, apt-get autoremove, apt-get clean y apt-get autoclean

Comment: Intenta reinistalar apache2 y apache2-bin con `sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2 apache2-bin`.

Comment: Me sale un mensaje de que ocurrió un error al tratar de instalar "apache2-bin" ya que tiene problemas con unas dependencias.
Normalmente cuando me pasaba eso usaba: 
apt-get install -f y se arreglaba, pero al usar ese comando me regresa al error original y no puedo arreglarlo

Comment: Podrías probar instalando synaptic y luego instalando apache desde synaptic para que te resuelva las dependencias implícitas. Yo he tenido que hacer eso para instalar varios paquetes en la 16.10, incluyendo Chrome

Comment: Lo peor es hacer un rm -rf , eso es para ficheros , para programas , el sudo apt-get remove o purge , que saben más sitios en los que estará que tu como usuario , yo también he caido en ese problema , pero nada ánimo

Answer (score 1):

## De entrada

Borra la instalación que tienes con un :

sudo apt-get purge apache2 
o lo que tengas instalado

https://askubuntu.com/questions/50101/how-do-i-remove-the-lamp-stack-so-i-can-start-over

## Pasos

Tienes que reinstalar LAMP, **yo de vez de una instalación de paquete te aconsejo una instalación por separado me explico** . es mejor , es más seguro, más estable y tienes mayor control sobre lo que nadas.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2

sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Asçi instalamos las versiones de apache2 y mysql-server , ya puedes ejecutar tu `mysql -u  -p.

```
sudo apt-get intall libapache2-mod-auth php7.0-mysql
```

Instalamos los que harán posible que te conectes php con mysql , previamente se supone que tienes instalado php.

Ahora que tenemos instalado esto.

Accediendo a

```
localhost
```

o

```
127.0.0.1
```

Accederás a apache :

```
cd /var/www/html/prueba/
nano info.php
```

Yo siempre me creo este fichero para no tener que estar a cada dos por tres creadome un fichero con este comando , tengo una carpeta donde tengo la configuración y asi la consulto de golpe.

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

Accedes al link .

```
127.0.0.1/prueba/info.php
```

Si te sirve de ayuda perfecto , si no siempre queda para que le ayude a alguien , pero yo los paquetes de instalación de un servidor los veo liosos aparte de que no dan un control total de la plataforma a controlar y se aprende más.

Como es lógico todo dependerá de lo que uno quiera algo fácil y probar algo o en mi opinión enriquecerse en el proceso con cultura general que te servirá de ayuda en el día de mañana.

*Nota : Yo creo que lo más aconsejable es instalar la versión más actual de php , aunque si trabajas con mysql , de vez de mysqli , hay maneras de reactivarlo , pero lo mejor es pasar todo a mysqli. Es simple y puro avance tecnológico.*

Este [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu) me sirvio mucho  para instalar por primera vez un servidor web de forma autónoma.

Answer (score 0):

Desinstalar por completo el LAMP, incluyendo las carpetas temporales y volver a instalar con la cuenta de superusuario.

Comment: De hecho ya lo hice; utilice la siguiente secuencia:
1.- sudo service apache2 stop, 
2.- sudo apt-get purge apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2-common
3.-sudo apt-get autoremove
4.-whereis apache2
5.-sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2  

También usé: sudo apt-get --purge autoremove apache2*
Lo mismo con php y mysql, pero no me ha funcionado

Answer (score 0):

Ejecuta estos updates en modo administrador

```
sudo apt-get autoremove

sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -f install
```

Luego ya puedes instarlar apache2

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```